# Excel sorting issue (cannot sort chronologically)

Tags: excel, sorting, date, time

I have the following file with in column A the date + time.
Now I want to sort this chronologically, but no matter what i try, i cannot get it sorted by date/time. When i hit the filter button I don't even get Smallest to Largest as an option, but I only have A to Z (which also doesn't do the job)

[image: Text]

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: Change your text-that-looks-like-a-date to an actual date (number).

Comment: It seems like your A column is text not a number (date) so you can only sort it alphabetically. What does formula =VALUE(A1) return?

Comment: @user11222393 it gives me back this: 45111,53889

Comment: The date time column is formatted as text as such the sorting is not working, very easy way to resolve this issue, select the whole column and goto Data Tab --> First Step --> Delimited --> Second Step --> Do nothing --> Third step --> click on date and select MDY and finish . Now the date time will be converted to actual excel date time values, lastly youc an sort now

Comment: @Luuk that number means those date time showing as text has been converted to number since in excel date and time are stored as numbers, hence you need to format them as per your preference and can sort a to z or z to a

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Data Tab --> First Step --> Delimited --> Second Step --> Do nothing --> Third step -->

I am not really following what to do here? Im in the data tab now...

Comment: When you are in the Data Tab --> Select the Text To Columns --> In the First Step --> Delimited --> Next --> Second Step --> Do Nothing --> Next --> Third Step --> Click on Date --> MDY --> Finish. Sorry I missed that part, while typing

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the Data Tab --> Select the Text To Columns --> In the First Step --> Delimited --> Next --> Second Step --> Do Nothing --> Next --> Third Step --> Click on Date --> MDY --> Finish. Sorry I missed that part, while typing –
thanks to @Mayukh Bhattacharya for the comment

Comment: You can accept your own solution to close the post. BTW you could have posted this query in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) as it is not related with programming.